# Error "socket hang up" - ECONNRESET

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets

I have a node.js application running on AWS EC2 and RDP MySQL instance. When i run a certain DB operation, the error below on the console. But I notice that the operation is performed correctly. Also these messages appears about 20 seconnds after the action. My suspicion is that the action is waiting for something after the completion of the action. When it does not get what ever it is expecting, it throws this error.

Can someone please advise? Thank you

```
Number of evaluations found: 41
GET /api/evaluation/all_evaluations/203 304 5.931 ms - -
*
{ Error: socket hang up* at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:252:15) at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:344:23) at emitNone (events.js:91:20) at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
POST /storedata/postdata?from=post%20SSQ%20ID&time=1475443962305 - - ms - -
POST /storedata/postdata?from=post%20SSQ%20ID&time=1475443962337 - - ms - -
POST /storedata/postdata?from=post%20SSQ%20ID&time=1475443962290 - - ms - -
*
{ Error: socket hang up* at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:252:15) at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:344:23) at emitNone (events.js:91:20) at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
*
{ Error: socket hang up* at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:252:15) at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:344:23) at emitNone (events.js:91:20) at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' } { Error: socket hang up at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:252:15) at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:344:23) at emitNone (events.js:91:20) at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Comment: My guess is that the other party is waiting for input (such as a logon: username or password or other respons) and terminates the connection after xx seconds. Could also be a bridge/firewall, etc.

Comment: but it performs the task

Comment: Aha, it is a webthingy. Could be a keep_open tning out.

Comment: I feels the issue is like a "keep_open tning out" thingy. But how do I fix it?